# Filter on list of list pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that that contains a list for one of the column. 
Example

```
df.loc[x,column] 
#returns [1,4,5,6]
```

I would like to select the row when the value is either 1 or 2 or 3.
I was thinking doing this in a list so I can filter like this :

```
filter = [1,2,3]
df_new = df[df[column] is in filter]
```

However, it returns me 
"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

if I try this :

```
filter = [1,2,3]
df_new = df[df[column].isin(filter)]
```

It returns me 
`<built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001E0CDF09440> returned a result with an error set`

I try to use any but it doesn't seem to work here.
I also had a look on the different thread posted with np.select  or using the pipe "|" but it doesn't really apply here. Does it ? 
Any tips ?

simplify example dataframe:

```
   column
0  [1,2]
1  [3,4]
2  [5]
3  []
4  [7,8]
5  [5,3]
```

Expected output (filtering for 1, 2 or 3):

```
   column
0  [1,2]
1  [3,4]
5  [5,3]
```

Comment: Could you please share a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to apply a custom function on the `column` which creates a *boolean* *mask*. This custom function checks each individual item of series to find if there are any elements in this item that are also present in the filter list.

Use:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3] # filter list
m = df[column].apply(lambda s: len(set(s) & set(lst)) > 0)
print(df[m])
```

This prints:

```
       column
0      [1, 2]
1      [3, 4]
5      [5, 3]
```

Comment: awesome ! Thank you very much. 
I was considering apply but it wasn't looking as elegant as this. 
For the final output, I did the df_new = df[m] and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need something more complex, you're pretty close to how you do it in pandas

```
df.loc[df[column].isin([filter])]
```

Comment: With this I see this error : <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x000001E0CDF09C10> returned a result with an error set

I see it as well when trying the following method: 

selection = df[df['column'].isin(filter)]

Comment: Is the value stored in the column a list?